# How can I remove, add or update a state with different actions with ngrx-store

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx-store

The first on() function its "_state" argument that you see below holds the values but the second on() function its "_state" argument doesn't hold any value so I'm not able to remove the data from it via Id.

I want that the retrievedBook and removeBook to be connected to the same _state so I can manage it's values from different function/actions.

```
export const bookReducer = createReducer(
  initialBook,
  on(book.retrievedBook, (_state, { book } ) => book),
  on(book.removeBook., (_state, { book } ) =>  _state.filter((id) => id.id != book) || [])
);
```

This is my action file:

```
export const ApiBooks = createActionGroup({
  source: 'Book API',
  events: { 
    'Retrieved book': props<{ book: Array<Book[]>{>(),
    'Remove Book': props<{ book: string}>()
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> but the second on() function its "_state" argument doesn't hold any value

You are forgetting to return the current `state` besides the changes, so for `retrievedBook` action (or any `action` actually) don't forget to include the current `state`

I don't know what's the shape of your Book reducer, so I'm gonna give you an example:

```js
export interface BookState {
  book: Book;
  books: Book[];
  authors: Author[];
}

export const initialState: BookState = {
  book: {...},
  books: [],
  authors: []
}

export const bookReducer = createReducer(
  initialBook,
  // here I am returning a new state with books and authors, as well as
  // the changes for book, so next time, in another action, the whole Book data
  // is preserved (books, book and authors)
  on(book.retrievedBook, (state, { book }) => ({...state, book}) ),
  ...  

  // or using the return keyword:
  on(book.retrievedBook, (state, { book }) => {
    // some logic here...
    return {
     ...state,
     book
    }
  }),
)
```

Comment: Hi @Andres2142, I understood how to return the actual state but I want to know how can I use the removeBook action with the same retrieveBook state because retrieveBook action state holds the api values and I want to be able to modify such values as require.